# Need to select only data that contains backslashes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backslash

I'm attempting to correct entries in a database that have been double-escaped.  I believe magic_quotes was on while mysql_real_escape_string was being used.  The double-escaping has caused some search results to be incorrect/missing.

I've turned magic_quotes off and am planning to search for entries with a backslash and update them to remove any double-escaping. Trouble is, when I perform a query to search for entries with backslashes, I always get no results.

```
SELECT title FROM exampletable WHERE title LIKE '%\\\\%'
```

I'm using '%\\\\%' as recommended here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

If I output every title, many of them have unwanted backslashes, so I know they're there.  I just can't seem to isolate them in a query.

```
Example Data:
Old King\'s Road
Running Down A Dream
Can\'t Stop The Sun
This One's For Me
```

Again, just trying to return entries with a \ in them.

---

EDIT: MySQL version is 5.0.92-community.  Collation is latin1_swedish_ci.  Charset is UTF-8 Unicode

%\\% does NOT work. I've tried.  It is listed as incorrect on mysql.com:

> To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Comment: You don't need to search for double slashes. Search for only `%\\%`. If you double escaped, one \ gets parsed correctly and your field data has one extra \, so you need to search for only one!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Please post your create table statement, along with the default character set and collation for your database.

Comment: MySQL version is 5.0.92-community.  Collation is latin1_swedish_ci.  Charset is UTF-8 Unicode.  Sorry, don't have the create table statement at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

This command works for me when I'm running the command with php:

```
select * from exampletable where title like '%\\\\\\\\%' or title like '\\\\\\\\%' or title like '%\\\\';
```

The reason I include the beginning, anywhere, and end matches is to show that they are different. If you're looking for backslashes on the end, there only needs to be 4 backslashes. this is because there is nothing to escape after it. You use 8 backslashes on the other commands because they get parsed by php.

Answer (score 2):

Your query works fine for me in MySQL 5.5.8:

```
mysql> create table exampletable (
  title varchar(255)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> insert into exampletable values ('Old King\\''s Road'),
  ('Running Down A Dream'),('Can\\''t Stop The Sun'),('This One''s For Me');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> select * from exampletable WHERE title LIKE '%\\\\%';
+---------------------+
| title               |
+---------------------+
| Old King\'s Road    |
| Can\'t Stop The Sun |
+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: I doubt that's the problem. Which charset and collation are you using for the server, table, and column?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT title FROM exampletable WHERE title LIKE '%\\%'
```

Comment: Yeah, forgot to say I tried that initially.  mysql.com says the quadruple \ is correct but neither seem to work for me.  I've tried any number of backslashes from 1 to 5 with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Ruby on Rails

```
search_value.gsub!(/\\/, "\\\\\\\\\\")
MyModel.where(["column_name ?","%#{search_value}%"])
```

If you don't want to use a wild card, add them.

```
search_value.gsub!(/%/, "\\%").gsub!(/_/, "\\_")
```