# What will be search query where the search key may contain special characters?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where a column allows special characters like <kbd>/</kbd> , <kbd>\</kbd> , <kbd>@</kbd> , <kbd>$</kbd> .

Now when I am trying to search such records from table, I am unable to get.
**I have tried one query but it is returning 0 rows but actually there is 1 record existing.** How to write a query in this case ?

My query (which is giving the wrong result) was something like this

```
select * from mytable where column7 like '%jk\xyz@%'
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490325/mysql-how-to-handle-query-search-with-special-characters-forward-slash-and)

Comment: @Saty : Yes. Its very similar problem with some good solutions too. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You may need to escape some special characters - particularly backslash. Note that with the LIKE operator - there is a two part process to issuing the command & both strip escaping - so to search for a single backslash you need to use 4 backslashes.

```
select * from mytable where column7 like '%jk\\\\xyz@%'
```

See this : [MySQL LIKE operator with wildcard and backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583144/mysql-like-operator-with-wildcard-and-backslash)
and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like