# Searching MySQL for data that contains backslashes

Tags: php, mysql

In a database, I have some text stored in a field call Description, the value of the string saved in my database is `Me\You "R'S'" %` and thats how it appears when querying the database command line.

Now, on a web page i have a function which searches this field as such:

> WHERE Description LIKE '%$searchstring%'

So when $searchstring has been cleaned, if i was searching for `Me\You`, the backslash gets escape and my query reads:

> WHERE Description LIKE '%Me\\You%'

However it doesn't return anything.

Strange part of this, is that when i search Me\\You or Me\\\You (So two or three backslashes, but no less or no more) it will return the result i expect with one backslash.

When querying for the result command-line, it does not return a result for:

> WHERE Description LIKE '%Me\You%'

or when i use two or three backslashes.

However it will return the result if i use 4 - 7 backslashes, for example:

> WHERE Description LIKE '%Me\\\\\\\You%'

will return the string which is `Me\You "R'S'" %`

Anyone have a reason to this happening? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**
>   Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “`\n`” to represent a newline character), you must double any “`\`” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “`\n`”, specify it as “`\\n`”. To search for “`\`”, specify it as “`\\\\`”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Need to select only data that contains backslashes in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625698/need-to-select-only-data-that-contains-backslashes-in-mysql) to see how to use double backslash escaping. You could also run MySQL in NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes)

Answer (score -3):

Although an old post, you can bypass this limitation using replace function to change backslash to another character: something like this in the WHERE clause. EXAMPLE:
WHERE  replace('your field here', '\', '-')  like "You-Me%"

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @user2966910 this isn't really sustainable in a text field which is free to allow any character as if the user enters a `-` (in this case) it will then come back out as a slash.

Comment: You also lose any performance benefits that you might otherwise gain from having an index on the column this way.