# SQL - How to search for a string that contains backslash

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like, backslash

I'm trying to find all entries that contain a backslash anywhere, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE bodyType LIKE '%\\%'
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE bodyType LIKE '%\\\\%'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE bodyType LIKE '%\\\\\\\\%'
```

Neither worked. Anyone know how to do this?

I am running the commands in MySQL Quick Admin v1.5.4

Comment: This should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214509/what-does-backslash-mean-in-an-sql-query

Comment: Thanks but there is nothing new there. I'm following the rules in my statement, it should work but it is not working. I know because there should be results and there are no results returned.

Comment: May you provide some sample data?

Comment: That is a forward slash and did nothing.

Comment: Read this....this is specifically for MySQL :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625698/need-to-select-only-data-that-contains-backslashes-in-mysql

Comment: Sorry for my initial comment (since deleted). Your second query (`SELECT * FROM animals WHERE bodytype LIKE '%\\\\%';`) is what worked on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0eeb1/2

Answer (score 0):

This question has not answer.

You try to match searching of content with backslash on names of columns.

Your (a bit general) query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName LIKE '%\\%'
```

will give you any result if content of any column will contain backslash. In this case your query is correct. But you cannot match name of any column.

I looked into some books I have and all they say the same: this will select all *records* written in column of chosen name that are containing backslash. But columns have to be chosen exactly (they cannot be selected by name with using of SQL query).

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. I am not trying to match column names. I will edit my question to get rid of the confusion you've experienced.

Comment: Then I beg your pardon.